# How to distribute work equally among workers by total count and total value?

Tags: c#, algorithm, mathematical-optimization

I have a problem tackling a distribution problem.

I have workers and workCases. Each workCase has an value. I need to distribute workCases so that all workers get equal number of cases with similar total value (if possible).

Number of total cases and workers is random.

What's the best way to solve this? I'm completely stuck.

My first idea was just to order them by value and just give them out like this:

```
public class WorkCase
{
    public decimal Value { get; set; }
}

public class Worker
{
    public List<WorkCase> Cases { get; set; }
}

public static void Sort(List<WorkCase> cases, List<Worker> workers)
{
    cases = cases.OrderByDescending(c => c.Value).ToList();

    var wCount = workers.Count;

    int i = 0;

    while (cases.Any())
    {
        workers[i].Cases.Add(cases.First());

        if (i == workers.Count - 1)
           i = 0;
        else
           i++;
    }
}
```

But thats just not really fair towards the last worker.
Thanks for help.

Comment: See if this helps you out: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/29709/algorithm-to-distribute-items-evenly

Comment: And if a worker finishes work should that value be removed? Or is this just a scheduling exercise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Morinator already addressed, this is a variation on the knapsack problem and no perfect solutions exist (other than sheer brute forcing and being lucky enough to have numbers that fit perfectly).

But you can get reasonably close. It's important to note that bigger cases are less flexible than smaller cases. Using a real world example, if I want you to *precisely* fill a given container, it's easier to do using sand than it is to do using pebbles or even rocks.

This real world example actually helps a lot here. If you want to pack that container while maximizing the rock/sand ration (i.e. as many rocks as you can), you first fill the container with rocks and then fill the gaps using the sand.

You can use exactly the same approach here, which you already attempted: assign the largest cases first and the smallest cases last. However, your code suffers from bugs because you repeatedly assign the largest case instead of moving on to the next case.

Because you have multiple workers, a secondary consideration is relevant: divide the large cases among them as best as you can. The easiest way to do this is to always assign a case to worker with the currently lowest work load (and in cases of ties, it doesn't matter who you pick, just pick the first of the tied workers).

Fixing your code:

```
public static void Sort(List<WorkCase> cases, List<Worker> workers)
{
    cases = cases.OrderByDescending(c => c.Value).ToList();

    foreach(var case in cases)
    {
       // Find the worker with the lowest case load

       var workersByCaseLoad = workers.OrderBy(w => w.Cases.Sum(c => c.Value);
       var workerWithLowestCaseLoad = workersByCaseLoad.First();

       // Assign this case to that worker

       workerWithLowestCaseLoad.Cases.Add(case);
    }
}
```

This won't always net you a perfect solution with exactly matching case loads, but it's a reasonable approximation. There are some fringe examples where the outcome isn't optimal but those cases are rare.
To avoid these fringe cases, the complexity of your code would have to **dramatically** increase. In most situations, the cost isn't worth the benefit.

Do note that this is not the most performant possible solution as it involves many collection iterations. But assuming a *reasonable* amount of workers and case loads (let's say within one company as a spitballed boundary), given today's hardware it shouldn't be a problem. Some optimization can be done by manually tracking the total case load for each worker, something along the lines of:

```
var workersByCaseLoad = workers.OrderBy(w => w.TotalCaseLoad);
var workerWithLowestCaseLoad = workersByCaseLoad.First();

workerWithLowestCaseLoad.Cases.Add(case);
workerWithLostCaseLoad.TotalCaseLoad += case.Value;
```

It's not as clean (it requires you to manually handle the values and keep this in perfect sync at all times), but it does prevent having to iterate over each worker's assigned cases every time.

---

Interestingly, this system also works reasonably well in cases where the full case list is not known at the start of the processing (which means you can't sort the cases). As long as you assign the next case to the person with the lowest load, it will remain a similarly fair game.

You may end up with a less perfect solution if your last few cases were disproportionately large. Think of it this way: you've kept things balanced, and then one more massive case must be assigned. That's always going to cause problems.

But if you can't know the case list in advance, then you can't expect to sort them, and then you get a less-perfect-but-still-reasonably-balanced outcome.

Comment: @DavidWaldo: Well spotted. It's a correction artifact from an earlier version. Fixing now.

Answer (score 2):

This problem sounds like it could be NP-hard. Look at the [Knapsack-Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem), which is similar. If you weren't restricted on the number of cases for each worker, you could sort the `workCases` descending by `value` and then always assign the next `workCase` to the worker with the lowest current load. Note that even this algorithm doesn't necessarily produce an optimal result.

Another thing you could try is to to start off by assigning every worker the right count of random jobs and then repeadedly find the workers with the lowest and highest load and let them swap a heavy job from the worker with low load and a light job from the worker with big load.
Note that also this solution is only a heuristic that may not produce optimal results.

But again, this problem seems like it has no fast perfect solution, try to find a NP-hard problem and reduce it to your problem to show that is it not solvable (for you right now).

Comment: Also if the number of workers does not divide the numbers of cases, then there can't exist any solution. I guess that's taken care of.

Comment: In regards to your comment, how so? 2 workers, 3 cases (which take 2h, 3h, 5h) has a perfect solution yet 2 does not divide 3.

Comment: "so that all workers get equal ammount of cases", am I missunderstanding this?

Comment: You're correct to the letter of the question but given the weighting of the workcases (the `Value`) and the "random" amount of each (as per the question), it seems highly likely OP misspoke and intended to say "equal amount of total case value". If not, it would seem the weighting is irrelevant and the problem is trivial (simple division).